# Retrive some data store in session with codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, session

I need to store some data that i get via an ajax request on a method, and later retrive them when i call another method.

```
public function updateInt()
{  $this->load->library('session');
   $interval = $this->input->post('_interval');
   $aInt = array('my_interval' => $interval);
   $this->session->set_userdata('post', $aInt);
   $_interval_ = $this->session->userdata['post']['my_interval'];
   return $_interval_;
} 



 public function getInt()
   {
       $interval = $this->updateInt();
       // print $interval and do some stuff !!
   }
```

// This return a null, but I need the value set on the front-end by the user and passed with an ajax call to updateInt() method.
I need some help because I'm newbie with codeignter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set your sessions in your config.php do not leave the session save path null

Example

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Make sure session folder permission 0700

Make sure you are getting correct post data what your after

```
public function updateInt()
{  
    // You can autoload it in config/autoload.php saves loading every page
    $this->load->library('session');

    $aInt = array('my_interval' => $this->input->post('_interval'));

    $this->session->set_userdata('post', $aInt);

    // Use `(` and `)` not `[]`
    $interval = $this->session->userdata('post');

   return $interval;
} 



public function getInt()
{
   $interval = $this->updateInt();

   // Test
   echo $interval['my_interval'];

   // print $interval and do some stuff !!
}
```

Comment: @SoptareanuAlex Don't for get to accept answer if works.